# O365 - Multifactor Auth - Access Authentication Phone via Powershell

Tags: active-directory, office365, azure-activedirectory, two-factor-authentication

Is is possible to get/set Authentication Phone via Powershell? I found some old documentation that says this is possible via the old MSOnline module but I cannot find anything in the new AzureAD module.

**Old Property:** StrongAuthenticationUserDetails

**MSOnline Doc**

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-sspr-authenticationdata#set-and-read-authentication-data-using-powershell

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using below code, you can get a list of MFA enabled users with Authentication Phone number.

```
$Result=""   
$Results=@()  
Get-MsolUser -All | where{$_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State -ne ""} 
| foreach{
 $DisplayName=$_.DisplayName
 $MFAPhone=$_.StrongAuthenticationUserDetails.PhoneNumber
$Result=@{'DisplayName'=$DisplayName;'MFAPhone'=$MFAPhone}
$Results= New-Object PSObject -Property $Result
$Results | Select-Object DisplayName,MFAPhone | Export-CSV <FilePath> -Append -NoType
}
```

Else, you can try below PowerShell script.

https://o365reports.com/2019/05/09/export-office-365-users-mfa-status-csv/

[image]

Comment: were you able to run the MSOnline commands? I installed MSOnline module but still received the 'cmdlet not found' message on the commands in that module.

Comment: After installing MSOnline Module, you need to import MSOnline cmdlets using below cmd-let

`Import-Module Msonline`

Comment: I was able to run the MSOnline commands but did not return any data for myself even though I am enrolled in two-factor authentication.

Comment: I am wondering if the StrongAuthenticationUserDetails property is still supported.

Answer (score 1):

A little rewrite of [Kathy's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1495033/214658)

```
Get-MsolUser -All | where{
     $_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State -ne ""
} | Select  DisplayName,@{Name="MFAPhone";Expression={$_.StrongAuthenticationUserDetails.PhoneNumber}} | Export-CSV -NoType <Filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed, though it's important to note that the AzureAD module has not matured enough to *replace* the MSOnline (Msol) module altogether, yet.

To install the module please see later part of this page:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/connect-to-office-365-powershell

You need to create a **StrongAuthenticationMethod** object and use the `Set-MsolUser` cmdlet as follows:

I've written this script which contains all four strong authentication methods.  Adjust as required.

```
# Check Msol module installed and imported
If ((Get-Module -Name MSOnline)[0] -eq $null) {
    Install-Module -Name MSOnline -Force -AllowClobber
}
else
{
    Import-Module -Name MSOnline
}

# Popup login page if not logged in
Connect-MsolService

# Define variables (or adjust script to read from data source and loop)
$UserPrincipalName = "youruser@yourcorp.com"
$MobileNumber = "+01 234 567 890"
$AlternateMobiles = @("+02 345 678 901", "+03 456 789 012")

# Create new SAM objects
<#

    Supported SAM types:

    OneWaySMS            - Text code sent to mobile
    PhoneAppOTP          - Authenticator code
    PhoneAppNotification - Push notification
    TwoWayVoiceMobile    - Phone call

    Note: Probably not able to use the App methods unless enrolled
#>

$SAM1 = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationMethod
$SAM2 = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationMethod
$SAM3 = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationMethod
$SAM4 = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.Online.Administration.StrongAuthenticationMethod

# Configure as required
$SAM1.IsDefault = $true          # <<<< Is default method
$SAM1.MethodType = "OneWaySMS"
$SAM2.IsDefault = $false
$SAM2.MethodType = "PhoneAppOTP"
$SAM3.IsDefault = $false
$SAM3.MethodType = "PhoneAppNotification"
$SAM4.IsDefault = $false
$SAM4.MethodType = "TwoWayVoiceMobile"

$SAMethods = @($SAM1, $SAM2, $SAM3, $SAM4)

Set-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $UserPrincipalName -StrongAuthenticationMethods $SAMethods `
    -MobilePhone $MobileNumber -AlternateMobilePhones $AlternateMobiles
```

Comment: Were you able to run the MSOnline commands? I installed MSOnline module but still received the 'cmdlet not found' message on the commands in that module.

Comment: Yes.  If you run ```Get-Command -Module MSOnline``` do you get any results back?  ```Install-Module -Name MSOnline -Force -AllowClobber``` should install the module for you if you get nothing back.  See this page https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/connect-to-office-365-powershell for detailed instructions and requirements.